# Split comma separated string with quotes and commas within quotes and escaped quotes within quotes

Tags: java, regex

I searched even on page 3 at google for this problem, but it seems there is no proper solution.

The following string

```
"zhg,wimö,'astor wohnideen','multistore 2002',yonza,'asdf, saflk','marc o\'polo'"
```

should be splitted by comma in Java. The quotes can be double quotes or single. I tried the following regex

```
,(?=([^\"']*[\"'][^\"']*[\"'])*[^\"']*$)
```

but because of the escaped quote at 'marc o\'polo' it fails...

Can somebody help me out?

Code for tryout:

```
String checkString = "zhg,wimö,'astor wohnideen','multistore 2002',yonza,'asdf, saflk','marc \'opolo'";
Pattern COMMA_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(",(?=([^\"']*[\"'][^\"']*[\"'])*[^\"']*$)");
String[] splits = COMMA_PATTERN.split(checkString);
for (String split : splits) {
  System.out.println(split);
}
```

Comment: Is every comma a separator, or can there be commas within quotes that should be ignored?

Comment: yes the commas within quotes should be ignored

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?>[^,'\"]++|(['\"])(?>[^\"'\\\\]++|\\\\.|(?!\\1)[\"'])*\\1|(?<=,|^)\\s*(?=,|$))+", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(checkString);

while(m.find()) {
    result.add(m.group());
}
```

Comment: +1 but how much time you did you take to write this beast? :)

Comment: Thanks, few time, since I used subpatterns that I already know. The most difficult was to match empty items avoiding empty results that are not between two commas : `(?<=,|^)\\s*(?=,|$)`

Comment: I have thrown a few 'hard' things to split at this regex, and it has passed. One comment is that this **does not unescape** the results, it effectively only does a 'split'. You still need to go through the resulting values and unquote and unescape things. Also, I am not 100% confident that this will cover everything... but finding the proof is harder than I thought. Still, upvoted, and impressed.... thanks.

Comment: @rolfl: Thanks, I can comfirm that it will cover everything.

Comment: @rolfl: the reason the pattern doesn't remove quote is only to support this kind of items: `abc'def'ghi`

Answer (score 1):

Splitting CSV with regex is not the right solution... which is probably why you are struggling to find one with split/csv/regex search terms.

Using a dedicated library with a state machine is typically the best solution. There are a number of them:

- This closed question seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410538/which-is-the-best-csv-parser-in-java
- I have used opencsv in the past, and I beleive the apache csv tool is good too. I am sure there are others. I am specifically not linking any library because you should o your own research on what to use.
- I have been involved in a number of commercail projects where the csv parser was custom-built, but I see no reason why that should still be done.

What I can say, is that regex and CSV get very, very complicated relatively quickly (as you have discovered), and that for performance reasons alone, a 'raw' parser is better.

Comment: hmmm, what would be the best way to parse 'raw'? is there something like a character stream for strings?

Comment: Just an example, see line 211 of: http://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVParser.java

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing CVS (or something very similar) than using one of the stablished frameworks normally is a good idea as they cover most corner-cases and are tested by a wider audience thorough usage in different projects.

If however libraries are no option you could go with e.g. this:

```
public class Curios {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String checkString = "zhg,wimö,'astor wohnideen','multistore 2002',yonza,'asdf, saflk','marc o\\'polo'";
        List<String> result = splitValues(checkString);
        System.out.println(result);

        System.out.println(splitValues("zhg\\,wi\\'mö,'astor wohnideen','multistore 2002',\"yo\\\"nza\",'asdf, saflk\\\\','marc o\\'polo',"));
    }

    public static List<String> splitValues(String checkString) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Used for reporting errors and detecting quotes
        int startOfValue = 0;
        // Used to mark the next character as being escaped
        boolean charEscaped = false;
        // Is the current value quoted?
        boolean quoted = false;
        // Quote-character in use (only valid when quoted == true)
        char quote = '\0';
        // All characters read from current value
        final StringBuilder currentValue = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < checkString.length(); i++) {
            final char charAt = checkString.charAt(i);
            if (i == startOfValue && !quoted) {
                // We have not yet decided if this is a quoted value, but we are right at the beginning of the next value
                if (charAt == '\'' || charAt == '"') {
                    // This will be a quoted String
                    quote = charAt;
                    quoted = true;
                    startOfValue++;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (!charEscaped) {
                if (charAt == '\\') {
                    charEscaped = true;
                } else if (quoted && charAt == quote) {
                    if (i + 1 == checkString.length()) {
                        // So we don't throw an exception
                        quoted = false;
                        // Last value will be added to result outside loop
                        break;
                    } else if (checkString.charAt(i + 1) == ',') {
                        // Ensure we don't parse , again
                        i++;
                        // Add the value to the result
                        result.add(currentValue.toString());
                        // Prepare for next value
                        currentValue.setLength(0);
                        startOfValue = i + 1;
                        quoted = false;
                    } else {
                        throw new IllegalStateException(String.format(
                                "Value was quoted with %s but prematurely terminated at position %d " +
                                        "maybe a \\ is missing before this %s or a , after? " +
                                        "Value up to this point: \"%s\"",
                                quote, i, quote, checkString.substring(startOfValue, i + 1)));
                    }
                } else if (!quoted && charAt == ',') {
                    // Add the value to the result
                    result.add(currentValue.toString());
                    // Prepare for next value
                    currentValue.setLength(0);
                    startOfValue = i + 1;
                } else {
                    // a boring character
                    currentValue.append(charAt);
                }
            } else {
                // So we don't forget to reset for next char...
                charEscaped = false;
                // Here we can do interpolations
                switch (charAt) {
                    case 'n':
                        currentValue.append('\n');
                        break;
                    case 'r':
                        currentValue.append('\r');
                        break;
                    case 't':
                        currentValue.append('\t');
                        break;
                    default:
                        currentValue.append(charAt);
                }
            }
        }
        if(charEscaped) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Input ended with a stray \\");
        } else if (quoted) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Last value was quoted with "+quote+" but there is no terminating quote.");
        }

        // Add the last value to the result
        result.add(currentValue.toString());

        return result;
    }

}
```

Why not simply a regular expression?

Regular expressions don't understand nesting very well. While certainly the regular expression by Casimir does a good job, differences between quoted and unquoted values are easier to model in some form of a state-machine. You see how difficult it was to ensure you don't accidentally match an ecaped or quoted `,`. Also while you are allready evaluating every character it is easy to interpret escape-sequences like `\n`

What to watch out for?

- My function was not written for white-space arround values (this can be changed)
- My function will interpret the escape-sequences `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, `\\` like most C-style language interpreters while reading `\x` as `x` (this can easily be changed)
- My function accepts quotes and escapes inside unquoted values (this can easily be changed)
- I did only a few tests and tried my best to exhibit a good memory-management and timing, but you will need to see if it fits your needs.